# Pandas .resample() or .asfreq() fill forward times

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I'm trying to resample a dataframe with a time series from 1-hour increments to 15-minute.  Both `.resample()` and `.asfreq()` do almost exactly what I want, but I'm having a hard time filling the last three intervals.

I could add an extra hour at the end, resample, and then drop that last hour, but it feels hacky.

Current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00', freq = '1H'), 'num':5})
df = df.set_index('date').asfreq('15T', method = 'ffill', how = 'end').reset_index()
```

Current output:

```
                 date  num
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00    5
1 2018-01-01 00:15:00    5
2 2018-01-01 00:30:00    5
3 2018-01-01 00:45:00    5
4 2018-01-01 01:00:00    5
```

Desired output:

```
                 date  num
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00    5
1 2018-01-01 00:15:00    5
2 2018-01-01 00:30:00    5
3 2018-01-01 00:45:00    5
4 2018-01-01 01:00:00    5
5 2018-01-01 01:15:00    5
6 2018-01-01 01:30:00    5
7 2018-01-01 01:45:00    5
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about `asfreq` but `reindex` works wonderfully:

```
df.set_index('date').reindex(
      pd.date_range(
          df.date.min(), 
          df.date.max() + pd.Timedelta('1H'), freq='15T', closed='left'
      ), 
      method='ffill'
)

                     num
2018-01-01 00:00:00    5
2018-01-01 00:15:00    5
2018-01-01 00:30:00    5
2018-01-01 00:45:00    5
2018-01-01 01:00:00    5
2018-01-01 01:15:00    5
2018-01-01 01:30:00    5
2018-01-01 01:45:00    5
```

Comment: Bingo - thanks Coldspeed.  Stay tuned, I got another one for you.

Comment: @pshep123 Sure thing :)